# systemjs.config.js relative path in hosted enviornment 404 (Not Found)

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, systemjs

This is a aspnet core + angular 2 project.
My site is not able to find (404 Not Found) the js files in hosted environment. It runs fine in the developemnt enviornment from the VS2015.

In my Development environment, my angluar2 files are located under my aspnetcore_project_directory/wwwroot/app folder.

The main app file for angular2 is in aspnetcore_project_directory/wwwroot/app/main.js

The contents systemjs.config.js

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': 'node_modules/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            app: 'app',
            // angular bundles
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
            // other libraries
            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
            'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api'
        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            app: {
                main: 'main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'angular-in-memory-web-api': {
                main: 'index.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

This setup is fine when I was testing under development environment in vs2015.
I copied the published content to IIS. The folder structure here is **inetpub\wwwroot\myprj** so under **inetpub\wwwroor\myprj\wwwroot\app** I have the angular files.

I launch my site as

> http: //example.com/myprj

and all aspnet related code loads properly. But when it tries to load the angular module, it is trying to load the main.js from

> http: //example.com/app/main.js

instead of

> http: //example.com/myprj/wwwroot/app/main.js

I am not sure If I haven't copied the files to right location or not referencing it properly in the systemjs file or both or ..

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="/">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Index - myprj</title>


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/myprj/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/myprj/css/site.css" />



</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/myprj">myprj</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="/myprj/SiteManager">Stats</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/myprj">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/myprj/Home/About">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/myprj/Home/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>

    <form method="post" id="logoutForm" class="navbar-right" action="/myprj/Account/LogOff">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
                <a title="Manage" href="/myprj/Manage">Hello padhu@adsc.com!</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link navbar-btn navbar-link">Log off</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="CfDJ8KehTnO-SvNKgU7UYNtLOEZOnq1O6ETchwbvuVHy4sOk8JDjACikATgFczHo5p0CZiGbPYRpa4cZ0Kx43DFrV9JidqSTjTMdAFcAu_YBlXl54-m0NRAvtOVIZudX7Rm7MD7y006yAcfujAaPK72-j2AGf2L50f7CSxpUyH964Mi22A4IxgVgerkO9aja_rYEow" /></form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid body-content">


    <!-- Css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/myprj/css/site.css" /><link rel="stylesheet" href="/myprj/css/site.min.css" /><link rel="stylesheet" href="/myprj/css/spinkit.css" />
    <!-- Js -->
    <script src="/myprj/lib/jQuery/dist/jquery.js"></script>

    <script src="/myprj/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js"></script>    
    <script src="/myprj/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.js"></script>
    <script src="/myprj/node_modules/zone.js/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="/myprj/node_modules/reflect-metadata/reflect.js"></script>




<!-- Configure SystemJS -->
<script src="/myprj/js/systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>
<my-app>Loading...</my-app>

        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; 2016 - myprj</p>
        </footer>
    </div>


        <script src="/myprj/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="/myprj/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="/myprj/js/site.js?v=PO_8e6bIDi7De8_fdNEN0tfEE9tOM_13R3l4268U5_Y"></script>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, I don't know much about Angular2, but I'll try to help. Can you update your question showing how you're including the `main.js` in your html page ?

Comment: @FabricioKoch I do not include main.js explicitly. I believe in my setup, the angular framework looks up the package loader systemjs.config.js  to get the main.js. For instance if I change the "main" in above code to main: 'myprj/wwwroot/app/main.js'.. then the loader tries to load from http ://mysite.com/app/myprj/wwwroot/app/main.js

Comment: Ok, but is there any includes in your html page?

Comment: included my index.html

Comment: I changed the 'app' under 'map' of my sytemjs.config.js to app: 'myprj/wwwroot/app/'. now it does try to load the file from http ://mysite.com/myprj/wwwroot/app/main.js  but still fails (404), though the file is in that folder.

Comment: I see you're including files that are outside the `wwwroot` folder. The `wwwroot` folder is the public folder. All your files (scripts, css, ..) should be there so you can make a reference to them.

Comment: For example, run your app, and then, try to access the `systemjs.config.js` file writing the URL on your browser. E.g. "www.mysite.com/myprj/js/systemjs.config.js". If I'm right, you won't be able to get this file..

Comment: The systemjs.config.js is under myprj/wwwroot/js folder. Since my site is hosted on a aspnetcore platform though the html refer to /myprj/js/systemjs.config.js, it knows to render the static file from wwwroot folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the site is running in a subdirectory, I had to change **base** in _Layout.cshtml file.

Changed it from

```
<base href="/">
```

to

```
<script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
</script>
```

This solved almost all of the reference issues because of hosting in subdirectory.

Comment: I use `<base href="@Url.Content("~/")">`. I think it's easier to understand.